# Работа с аудиофайлами в питон

Tags: python, аудио

Ищу библиотеку для преобразования аудиофайла в байт-код и последующей работой с ним.

Я пробовал librosa. Но после дня работы с этой библиотекой, ничего не вышло.
Насколько я понял, эта библиотека требует установленную и настроенную анаконду или опытного наставника.
Ни того ни другого у меня нет.

Так код:

```
print('1')

import librosa

filename = 'Techno - Tetris (Remix).wav'

print(filename)

y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

print('3')

tempo, beat_frame = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr)

print('tempo: {:.2f}'.format(tempo))
```

печатает: 1
И я не понимаю, почему...

Имеется также библиотека FMOD. Но качество её документации оставляет желать лучшего. Также она сильно уступает librosa.

Comment: Наверное всё же нужно искать библиотеки для чтения аудиофайлов конкретного формата. У вас какого формата аудио файлы?

Comment: @CrazyElf формат mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с pygame.mixer.sound работать. [Тут](https://russianblogs.com/article/7419885858/) про него много написано ([russianblogs.ru](https://russianblogs.com/article/7419885858/))

Comment: Вообще там достаточно функций

Comment: Как оказалось, с её помощью можно даже ритм-игры делать... Вероятно, я её сильно недооценил.

Comment: Ага, там можно даже включать мелодию с определённой секунды. Если вам интересно, вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344615/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-qmediaplayer-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-mp3-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-pyqt5/1344641#1344641) на вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Одна из самых известных библиотек для работы со звуковыми файлами в питоне это [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa), она умеет довольно многое.

Comment: При попытке работы с этой библиотекой, мне пишет ошибку:

 raise ImportError("Numba needs NumPy 1.20 or less")

Устанавливаю нужную версию NumPy командой:

pip3 install NumPy==1.20

Ошибка никуда не пропадает.

Comment: Я новичок в питоне, и могу ошибаться. Так что поправьте, если я что-то упустил.

Comment: А у вас чистый питон или anaconda какая-нибудь? Правильно настроить питон и библиотеки - это бывает весьма непростая задача

Comment: Чистый... Ранее устанавливал несколько библиотек, но сам питон скачан с официального сайта.

Comment: Ну вот там видимо требуется `Numba`, а её в чистом питоне установить не так то просто. А она в свою очередь зависит от `Numpy`. И всё это нужно согласовать по версиям.