# Как с помощью QMediaPlayer запустить mp3 с определенной секунды PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Пишу MP3-Player. Научился запускать песню, приостанавливать, находить ее длительность, но метода в QMediaPlayer по включению mp3 с определенной секунды так и не нашел. Есть ли такой метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В QMediaPlayer вроде бы нету, а вот в Pygame есть, попробуйте, ответ скопировал с [question-it](https:////question-it.com/questions/1306283/kak-nachat-muzyku-v-opredelennuju-sekundu-v-pygame)

*Вот рабочий фрагмент, протестированный как на Windows 10, так и на Android. Обратите внимание, что музыкальный файл представляет собой mp3!*

```
import pygame.mixer

#SOUND_FILE = 'c:/temp/JMJ.mp3'
SOUND_FILE = '/storage/emulated/0/music/JMJ.mp3'

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(SOUND_FILE)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=1626) # 1626 seconds from beginning

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.wait()
```

***Конечно, работа с двумя и более модулями не очень, но хотя-бы как-то...***

Comment: Спасибо! Чуть позже опробую

Comment: В любом случае уже есть хоть какой-то вариант

Comment: Ну да, хоть какой-то есть. Я сам недавно работал, сайт в истории нашёл

Comment: Получилось! Правда немного специфично))

Comment: Главное, чтобы работало)))

Comment: Основополагающий принцип))

Comment: Все-таки метод есть, setPosition(int)  в PyQt

Comment: да??? искал буквально неделю, не нашёл, а то бы помогло :(

Comment: Спасибо еще раз)